# Do I need a Windows server license if I have an Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, licensing, virtual-server

I am trying to do a cost analysis on using Azure. Can anyone tell me if I will need to purchase Windows server licenses when spinning up virtual servers in Azure.  Also, will the users need CALS for touching these servers?

Answer (score 2):

Any supported Windows OS image running on Windows Azure does not have licensing cost associated with it, your hourly price for the CPU core usage has that included.

When you select a Windows Server OS based virtual Machine, directly from Windows OS Gallery, the OS image is activated within Windows Azure Licensing server. Same goes with the Windows OS based VHD which you create on-premise using Windows Server and Hyper-V and then upload the Windows Azure. Once your uploaded OS image is running in Windows Azure it will be use activation process within Window Azure as well.

If you decide to create OS image VHD on-premise you do need a licensed Windows Server OS with Hyper-V to create the OS Images and that's all you can include for your cost analysis.

Answer (score 1):

No server license needed.  The license is included in the per hour charge for the VM.